# How can I configure enhanced measurements for a Google Analytics: App + Web property created from Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I am implementing Google Analytics App + Web for my website using a property I created from my Firebase project.

In the documentation, I keep reading about configuring enhanced measurements to automatically capture things like page views, file downloads, or outbound clicks.

From various articles online, my guess is that enhanced measurements are configured in the Data Streams admin section of GA. However, I can only see the text "Stream configurations in Firebase" with no option to configure it from the GA console and I wasn't able to find any way to configure these from the firebase console either.

1. Is there any way to configure enhanced measurements in this case?
2. Does firebase creates the data stream with a default configuration for enhanced measurements and what would that be?
3. Should I just ignore these and log events manually reusing the same event keys?

FYI, in my debugView, I am seeing some page_view events, but none of the others.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this issue? I'm encountering the same problem.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, would love an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well. I resolved it by [unlinking analytics from Firebase](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9289234?authuser=0). After that, Google Analytics let me configure Data Streams, i.e. I no longer saw the "Stream configurations in Firebase" message.

Update: actually, don't do this. The only reason it worked was that it was compounding with a different bug related to unlinking and relinking. See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/4291 for more info.

Answer (score -1):

You have to link Link Google Analytics to Firebase: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9289234?hl=en

Comment: Thanks but I believe my Firebase project and Google Analytics property are properly linked. I can follow the link from Firebase to GA (and vice versa); and I can see the page_view events in the GA debugView even though I am only using the firebase sdk in the code.

Comment: @KillianHuyghe  Were you ever able to figure this out?  I'm in the same boat. It seems we can't configure this in the Firebase admin.  My guess is because it's a feature added after FirebaseAnalytics was forked to GA4.